# UILabel stops truncating when constraint is applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am working with a tableview, which looks like this:

[image]

Now, when I center the labels vertically so that they don't overlay the borders of the cells, the text in the label suddenly is not truncating anymore.

[image]

Does anybody know whats the logic behind this, because I cannot see why it would behave like this and it is just bugging me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also set a width constraint or left/right constraints?  Labels are a special case because they often expand themselves when the constraints are set up to allow this.  I'm guessing once you added constraints, you didn't specify a max width, so the label expands as far as it needs to to fit the text.  Set a left/right inset, or a max width and your problem should be solved.

Comment: but why would it expect a constraint for width more after adding a vertical center constraint, than before doing it. the vertical center constraint and one for width are separate are they not?

Comment: Because before it was dependent on autoresizing mask translation that was providing a width constraint among other things that were absolute based on the frame you gave it in interface builder.  Once you added the first constraint, the autoresizingMask is no longer translated to constraints, so the only constraint the label knows about is the vertical center.  Because of this, it assumes you want it to grow with text.  If you set the width, or left / right constraints explicitly, it will not do this.

Comment: Hmm, it just "sounds" like an autoresizing mask would be more likely to "resize" width or whatever; the only times I've used the property is when i wanted to apply flexible stats. Thx for your reply tho, it put some sense in it for me.